# building development environment for GWT with JBoss

Tags: eclipse, gwt, development-environment, jboss5.x

I am using eclipse IDE and want to build up a development environment for creating an app.

I have an EJB module on Jboss5 and would like to add a GWT project.

I could see that GWT during development is executed on it's development host mode, but the problem is that in this case I can not local EJB services deployed on my JBoss.

Is there anyway to overcome this challenge? how can I use the eclipse along with JBoss to develop, run and debug GWT application? I don't mind using ANT script in order to compile and deploy on JBoss, just need to know if this is possible (Also to debug the GWT application).

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample setup to use JBoss Tools with GWT and GWT Plugin. http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UseJBossToolsWithGoogleGWTPlugin

Comment: no longer works with recent Chrome, JBoss, Eclipse and JBoss tools versions... unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Strelok's sample page now recommends following the guidelines for creating a GWT project using a general Eclipse Web Tool Project approach.

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateGWTProjectsWithJBossToolsAndEclipseWTP